# Does atomic_inc_return() guarantee atomic return value?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Imagine the following use-case:

```c
static atomic_t ref_counter = ATOMIC_INIT(0);

void incref(void) {
    if (atomic_inc_return(&ref_counter) == 1) {
        // init my stuff
    }
}

void decref(void) {
    if (atomic_dec_return(&ref_counter) == 0) {
        // release my stuff
    }
}
```

If two threads simultaneously call `incref()`, `ref_counter` is guaranteed to have value `2` after both calls.

But does the atomic execution get applied to the return value too? I mean, are we guaranteed that one of the threads will return `1` while the second one returns `2`? Or they both may return `1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But does the atomic execution get applied to the return value too?

That's the whole point of these functions, otherwise they wouldn't make much sense. The whole point of `atomic_*_return` is that modification of the variable and fetching the value happens *atomically*.

> I mean, are we guaranteed that one of the threads will return 1 while the second one returns 2?

Yes. Atomic accesses are *sequenced* with each other.

> Or they both may return 1?

No.